# jQuery is not firing click on label tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, click, label

it has been impossible to attach a click event on label tags but I can't see why.

The jQuery lib is at:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('label').('click', function () {
            alert("this is the click on label!");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

on my View MVC 2.0 page I have a for to fech a list of countries, to bind a set of checkboxes:

```
<label><input id='country_<%=country.CountryID%>' 
       type="checkbox" name="country" value="on"/> <%=country.CountryName %>
</label><br />
```

When I click on the `label` nothing happens on IE9, Chrome 12 or Firefox 5.

Comment: I noticed that there is some issue when putting a transparent image floating above my `label`. When I move the label outside this divs or comment the floating transparent image, the label click works again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$("#foo").bind('click', function(){
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

You appear to have left out the `bind` method name. Alternatively, you can set the click by directly accessing the click method:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
  alert("Clicked");
});
```

Comment: Yes it is working now with Click, also I have changed to jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label').click(function () {
        alert("this is the click on label!");
        return false;
    });
});
```